# ExtJS: where to define prototypical extensions of base classes?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Say I want to extend `Number` or `String` ect by adding functions to their respective prototypes

Where do I put the code for this in an ExtJS 4 application so that it's available everywhere?

I've tried putting all my `Number.prototype.<whatever>`'s in a seperate file `app.prototypes` and then appending this file in my `requires` config for my `Ext.application` ... but then the application *fails silently* (doesn't load, no errors).

Advice?

This is what I have... but its not working:

```
Ext.define('PT.overrides.Number', {
override: 'Ext.Number',

constructor:function(config) {
    var me = this;

    me.callParent(arguments);

    me.formatMoney = function(c, d, t) {
        console.log('called');              // never called
        var result;
        // blah, blah
        return result;
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't augment base prototypes, that is bad style shunned in all major JavaScript frameworks by now. Either extend Ext.Number in a new class like Trendy suggests, or just use [Ext.util.Format](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Format) methods - no need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: I live in the docs nowadays lol ... just havn't been through them all I guess lol

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Ext Define to define/extend the class:

```
Ext.define('Your.Class.Name' /*null for anonymous class*/, {

     extend:'Ext.Number' /*class to extend*/,

     constructor:function(config) {

          this.initConfig(config);

          return this;
     }
});
```